# How to bind a request object to a static method in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, dependency-injection

I want to implement dependency injection inside my server with the following limitations:

- My API should be created once and is external and unchangeable
- My API exposes a method (via ctor) which I can supply
- My API wants to log messages using request based data
- I'm enriching my request with the services I created
- In case there are two simultaneous requests, I want each to use its own requests with no way for the contexts to get mixed

```
function createApi() {

  const requestParam = {};

  function logMessage(msg: string) {
     logger.log(reqUrl, reqSessionId, msg);
  }

  const api = new ExternalApi({ logMessage });

  function createRequestContext(request: Request) {
      requestParams.url = request.url;
      requestParams.sessionId = request.sessionId;
      return { api };
  }

  return { createRequestContext };
}
```

The node middleware I want to use to enrich the request:

```
import { RequestHandler, Request } from 'express';

export const bootstrapRequestContext = (): RequestHandler => {
    const { createRequestContext } = createApi();

    return (request: Request, _, next) => {
        const { api } = createRequestContext(request);
        request.api = api;
        next();
    };
};
```

Inside my routers:

```
router.get('some-url/', (request) => {
  request.api.doSomething();
});
```

This of course wouldn't work, since each request would update the "static" parameters which would override valued from another simultaneous request.

I want a solution that enables me to create `ExternalApi` once (since this might be a taxing action) but provide request params based on the current request.